# ERROR EN: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de instalar `crea8SOCIALPRO V6.2.1`, Pero cuando instalo la `db` me redirige a

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in
>   /public_html/includes/core.php on line 1015.

Este es el código que me da error:

```
public static function getSitePages() {
        if (cache_exists("site-pages")) {
            return get_cache('site-pages');
        } else {
            $query = db()->query("SELECT * FROM static_pages");
            $pages = array();
            //echo db()->error;
             while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $pages[$fetch['slug']] = $fetch;
            }
            set_cacheForever("site-pages", $pages);
            return $pages;
        }
```

La linea 1015 seria  `while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: Por alguna razón, db()->query() no te está devolviendo un objeto. Puedes hacer varias cosas, comprobar que la consulta `"SELECT * FROM static_pages"` devuelve resultados ejecutándola directamente en tu base de datos. Prueba también a hacer un `var_dump($query)` para ver qué tipo de variable es. Con los resultados de esas dos cosas, vuelve aquí y coméntalo, así podemos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a poner: `$result->fetch_array()`

La solución seria:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM static_pages";
$result = db()->query($query);

$total_num_rows = $result->num_rows;

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Intente y me sigue saliendo `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object on line 1015 in /home/u358991597/public_html/includes/core.php`

Comment: Entonces puede ser que la query esta mal hecha @PhoenixSG

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate bien siempre en los errores que te lanza `PHP` o cualquier otro lenguaje.

> Call to a member function **fetch_assoc()** on a **non-object** in /public_html/includes/core.php on line 1015.

En este caso el error te está indicando que estas intentando ejecutar la función `fetch_assoc()` desde una `variable` que no es un objeto y por eso falla.

Dicha llamada la tienes en `$row = $result->fetch_array()`, donde estás pasando tu sentencia `$result`, donde debería estar tu fallo.

### Estilo orientado a objetos MySQLi

Dejo un ejemplo como prodria quedar:

**Conexión PHP:**

```
//Variables conexión.
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$contrasena = "Tu_contraseña";
$bd = "mi_base_de_datos";

// Conexión
$conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena, $bd);

// Comprobamos conxexión
if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    exit("Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}
```

**Ejemplo sentencia:**

```
$sentencia = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM tu_tabla");

//Comprobar algun error al consultar nuestra consulta.
if(!$sentencia) {
   //Mensaje de error
   printf("Error consulta: %s\n" . $conexion->error);
}    

//Total registros.
$total_num_rows = $sentencia->num_rows;

//Comprobamos existencia de registros.
if ($total_num_rows > 0) {
    //Recuperamos una fila de resultados como un array asociativo.
    while ($row = $sentencia->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Ya podemos trabajos con nuestros datos.        
        echo $row['nombre_columna_a_mostrar'];
        #etc.
    }

} else {
    echo "0 resultados encontrados";
}


//Cerramos conexión.
$conexion->close();
```

> **Nota**: mi consejo es utilizar sentencias `prepare()` o `PDO`, veamos algunos motivos porque son tan solicitadas hoy un día la sentencias preparadas.

El principal y más esencial beneficio de las declaraciones preparadas es la eliminación de todos los peligros del formato manual:

- Declaración preparada hace el formateo completo. ¡Todo ello sin la
  intervención del programador!
- Declaración preparada que hace el formato adecuado (siempre y cuando
  estamos de unión a nuestros datos utilizando el tipo adecuado).
- Las declaraciones preparadas hacen el formateo invulnerable.
- Declaración preparada tiene el formato en el único lugar adecuado -
  justo antes de la ejecución de la consulta.

Es por esto que el formato manual está tan despreciado en la actualidad y declaraciones preparadas son tan honrado.

**Manual prepare():**

- https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

¡Un saludo!